# Structuremap 3.0 EqualToAppSetting

Tags: constructor, arguments, structuremap, structuremap3

I have upgraded to SM 3.0 and now, amongst other breaking changes I find that EqualToAppSetting is gone.

I used to be able to do

```
  .Use<SomeType>().Ctor<SomeType>("connectionStr").EqualToAppSetting("myAppSetting");
```

where of course myAppSetting is pulled from the app.config or the web.config.

Anyone know how to do that now? or some other work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it was deprecated in version3.

The recommended way to do this is fairly complex I think.
http://lostechies.com/joshuaflanagan/2009/07/13/how-we-handle-application-configuration/

A quick workaround would be to just create a variable called settings and is the Is method.

```
var settings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
x.For<ISearchStatsProvider>().Use<SearchStatsProvider>()
                             .Ctor<string>("solrUrl").Is(settings["SolrUrl"]);
```

Comment: yes seems that way, and yes your solution would work fine.  Was nice to have that other setting though. Thanks

Comment: Agreed. I thought it was very handy as well